# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN with hosting static website with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, web-hosting, static-site, bluehost, google-bucket

I followed the instructions on [hosting-static-website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#uploading) and successfully set up an website with the ip 34.120.167.35, where I am able to view my site.

My DNS and domain name are both provided by BlueHost. I used the TXT verification and have my SSL certificate [activated on Google's end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrzpD.png).

I also added my ip as an A record on [Bluehost's DNS config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QwqI.png).

Once everything is setup, I entered my domain name lihenghenrychang.com in the browser and worked. However, a day after, the domain name would give back the following error:
lihenghenrychang.com’s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Meanwhile, I can still successfully view my site at the ip 34.120.167.35.

I have no idea where the problem could be and how to resolve this issue. I think there's a problem with the DNS, however, the customer support from bluehost said I should contact Google in terms of the problem. Would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Actually, if you go to www.lihenghenrychang.com, you will be able to access your site but not with the naked domain (lihenghenrychang.com). I suspect this seems to be more an issue with the DNS. If you go to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/ and check you domain, you'll see there is no IP for the domain but in the other hand, for the www domain the IP is set correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue with DNS configuration. As I can see at the screenshot, you've configured records for `lihenghenrychang.com` and `www.lihenghenrychang.com`

[image: dns]

but only `lihenghenrychang.com` resolves:

```
$ dig lihenghenrychang.com @8.8.8.8
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
lihenghenrychang.com.   14399   IN      A       34.120.167.35
...

$ dig lihenghenrychang.com @1.1.1.1
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
lihenghenrychang.com.   14400   IN      A       34.120.167.35
...
```

and

```
$ dig www.lihenghenrychang.com @8.8.8.8
...
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.lihenghenrychang.com.      IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
lihenghenrychang.com.   299     IN      SOA     ns1.bluehost.com. dnsadmin.bluehost.com. 2020083001 86400 7200 3600000 300
...

$ dig www.lihenghenrychang.com @1.1.1.1
...
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.lihenghenrychang.com.      IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
lihenghenrychang.com.   300     IN      SOA     ns1.bluehost.com. dnsadmin.bluehost.com. 2020083001 86400 7200 3600000 300
...
```

As a result, `lihenghenrychang.com` is reachable:

[image: content]

but `www.lihenghenrychang.com` isn't:

[image: error]

**To solve this issues** you can try to follow the documentation [DNS Records Explained](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/dns-records-explained) and configure `A` record for `lihenghenrychang.com`:

> For example, an A Record is used to point a logical domain name, such
> as "google.com", to the IP address of Google's hosting server,
> "74.125.224.147".

and `CNAME` record for `www.lihenghenrychang.com`:

> These records point [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com...

If nothing helped, you should reach [Bluehost support](https://www.bluehost.com/help).

Comment: I modfied my CNAME and A records and now everything works. Thank you Serhii.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Please accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful.