# Site cannot be reached on static website deployed on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have followed this instructions to deploy a static website on App Engine
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website

But when I visit the website, I only get

> This site can’t be reached. XXXXX server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

My app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

I did not do anything besides that in the tutorial page.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) you linked.

---

The error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` stands for **non-existent domain**. Therefore, if you are using custom domain in GAE, I would recommend inspecting your domain first:

- Check if you can see it in your domain registrar account.
- Make sure your [DNS settings](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart) are correct.
- See if it is properly [mapped](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mapping-custom-domains) to Google.

---

Alternatively, try accessing it via different browser or/and on another network to see if it still gives you the same error.

---

Here are some similar threads that I could find: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654275/dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-with-hosting-static-website-with-google-cloud-platfo), [link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/968659/error-dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-google-cloud-platform-wordpress-site-custo), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236744/dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-error-on-google-cloud-run-service).

---

If none of the above helps, I would suggest contacting the [GCP technical support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) for a more detailed inspection.